# Some text is missing when reading html using urllib

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

I use the following function to read html from a website called e-liquid-recipes.com ([example link](https://e-liquid-recipes.com/recipe/1415693/Goofy%27s%20Juice)).

```
def read_html(url):
    # Create a custom opener with User-agent header which allows cookies.
    cookiejar = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
    opener.addheaders = [
        ('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0'), 
        ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    ]

    # Make the opener the (global) default opener (urlopen will use it).
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    # Open URL and read response.
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()
```

Each line in the list of concentrates has a class name 'recline' which lists the various information about a flavour concentrate like it's name, percentage, etc.

Using beautifulsoup to extract the recline divs gives this as an example (this is the same in the html text returned by read_html).

```
<div class="recline highlight flmis prmis">
 <div class="rlab" id="rfl1">
  <a href="https://e-liquid-recipes.com/flavor/8591">
   Acetyl Pyrazine 5% (
   <abbr title="The Flavor/Perfumer's Apprentice">
    TPA
   </abbr>
   )
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="runit" id="flu1">
  0.30
 </div>
 <div class="rdrops" id="fld1">
 </div>
 <div class="rgrams" id="flg1">
 </div>
 <div class="rpercent" id="flp1">
 </div>
 <br/>
</div>
```

Note that rdrops, rgrams and rpercent is missing the expected text (it's just a newline character). Why might this be the case?

Comment: Pure html doesn't contain this data, this fields filled using javascript executed after html loaded.

Comment: Thanks Olvin I didn't consider that. I think I've found the script in question. It looks like I can calculate the needed values from runit anyway so this may not be a lost cause.